# How can I use an SQL Select query in a VBA conditional statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, conditional-statements

I am trying to create an Access macro that will only run if it retrieves a specific value from a table.  I am trying to prevent the user from running the macro more than once per period.

```
If sqlquery = "select Step 3 from XX_STORE_VALUE" = "READY" Then 
   DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningsoff) 
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "00 UPDATE NEXT NR AND LD ACCRUAL", acViewNormal, acEdit 
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "00 UPDATE NEXT NR AND LD SALES", acViewNormal, acEdit 
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE STEP 3", acViewNormal, acEdit 
   DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningson) 
End If 

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Public Function GetQueryreturnedvalue(yourvalue As Integer)
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   ' Getting value from your query

   strSQL = "SELECT [Step 3] FROM XX_STORE_VALUE where yourcriteria = " & yourvalue & ""
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


   GetQueryreturnedvalue = rst![Step 3]

   If GetQueryreturnedvalue = "Yourspecificvalue" Then

   DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningsoff)
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "00 UPDATE NEXT NR AND LD ACCRUAL", acViewNormal, acEdit
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "00 UPDATE NEXT NR AND LD SALES", acViewNormal, acEdit
   DoCmd.OpenQuery "UPDATE STEP 3", acViewNormal, acEdit
   DoCmd.SetWarnings (warningson)

   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing

   End If

End Function
```